# javascript starnage issue , return undefined if block statements are used

Tags: javascript

```
function ok(){

return 
   { 
     home : "OK"
    };

}
```

when i code like this the function will return `undefined`

[image]

but if i just shift the `{` it starts working

```
function ok(){

return { 
     home : "OK"
    };

}
```

[image]

Is this somekind of auto adding ';' at the end of line ?

Comment: Yes, the engine is adding ';' at the end so you have a nice 'return;'

Comment: @jonhopkins thanks .. was unaware of any such thing ..

Comment: Might this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2846298/2509344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript engines insert semicolons at certain newline positions. So, your first code is really this:

```
return; 
    { 
       home : "OK"
    };
```

And it returns nothing.